# Power-Spectrum for Self-Organised Criticality

Tags: correlation-functions, stochastic-processes, complex-systems, critical-phenomena

In 1987 Bak, Tang and Weisenfeld  authored a paper [(link)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235741761_Self-Organized_Criticality) on Self-Organised Criticality, on how minimally stable self-organised systems propagate the perturbations it is subjected to, scale-freely - thus attempting a phenomenological explanation for ubiquity of scale-invariant spatial and temporal patters, respectively fractals and flicker ($\frac{1}{f}$) noises.

Here it is mentioned:

> The lack of a characteristic length scale leads directly to lack of characteristic time scale for fluctuations. As is well known, a random superposition of pulses of a physical quantity with a random distribution of lifetimes     $D(T)\approx T^{-\alpha}$ (weighed by the average value of the quantity during the pulse) leads to a power frequency spectrum $S(f)\approx f^{-2 + \alpha}$, so a power law frequency spectrum is equivalent to a power-law distribution of lifetimes.

I know Fourier transform of power-law is a power-law itself and from Wiener-Khinchin theorem, that autocorrelation function is Fourier transform of power-spectral density. But

1. what about the statement : `random superposition of pulses of physical quantity with random distribution of lifetimes`$D(T)\approx T^{-\alpha}$?

Although it intuitively makes some sense, but still seems out of formal grip. Can somebody please explain thoroughly what is meant here?

Comment: That quote is preceded by "We expect the perturbation to grow over all length scales [...]  leads directly to a lack of a characteristic time scale for the fluctuations." So, isn't $D(T)\approx T^{-\alpha}$ just an expression of their hypothesis?

Comment: Yes that's better way to look at it. But that doesn't clarify what I asked, 'random superposition of pulses of physical quantities'.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the exact point you're missing, but the "physical quantities" is not necessary, it's there only to remind the reader the model is relevant to physics, but here it's math; maybe "superposition" isn't the best word either, since it's a sequence of pulses, i.e., they are not simultaneous, but this is inconsequential for the statistical analysis; and "random" should refer to how the grains of sand are added to the pile.